# Detect cursor is over comment or string in Scintilla NET

Tags: scintilla, scintillanet

Is there any built in function in Scintilla.NET to detect the cursor is over a comment or string? I'd want to avoid the autocompletion to work when the user is typing comments or strings.

I'm aware I can scan the whole text backwards, searching for //, /* */ and pairs of " " but I'm almost sure there must be a built-in function to do that.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using a lexer, you can get the style number at the current caret postion and check to see if it corresponds with a string or comment. The Scintilla API for retrieving the style number is:

- [SCI_GETSTYLEAT(int pos)](http://www.scintilla.org/ScintillaDoc.html#SCI_GETSTYLEAT)

The [Scintilla.NET documentation](http://scintillanet.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=ScintillaNET%20Types&referringTitle=Documentation) states there are already some convenience APIs for detecting comments:

- `ScintillaNET.Scintilla.PositionIsOnComment(System.Int32)`
- `ScintillaNET.Scintilla.PositionIsOnComment(System.Int32,ScintillaNET.Lexer)`

But there does not seem to be anything equivalent for strings - so it looks like you'll have to roll your own by using the above Scintilla message with one of the `ScintillaNET.Scintilla.SendMessageDirect()` methods.

Comment: I'm using a lexer so the first answer worked, thus I didn't try the second one. Thanks! :)